# Searching and copying data

Tags: excel, function, search, indexing, copy

I have an Excel spreadsheet looking like this:

[image: Example sheet]

What I want to do:
If a name from column A is present in column D then copy the cell next to D to C

Basically I have a list of names in A and B and I have their corresponding phone numbers in E. But some are missing and some are extra so I need to search and find the right one to copy to the C column.
I don't know how to use VBA code so I need to figure something out with functions.

I have tried using IF, INDEX and MATCH functions but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C2 and copied down to suit please try:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2&" "&B2,D:D,0)),"")
```

though please note that this will not take say `Will` from one row and `Smith` from another to find the number for `Will Smith`.

Answer (score 0):

In C2 you can use this formula:

=IF(COUNTIF(D:D;A2&" "&B2)=1;LOOKUP(A2&" "&B2;D:D;E:E);"N/A")

Copy down if needed.